# Остановить setInterval внутри объекта

Tags: javascript

```js
let spins = {
  init: function(selector, i = 0, speed, pause = false) {
    let handle = setInterval(function() {
      i += 1;
      $(selector).css('transform', 'rotate(' + i + 'deg)');
      $(selector + ' .item-circle__image').css('transform', 'rotate(-' + i + 'deg)');
    }, speed);
    console.log(clearInterval(handle));
    if (pause == false) {
      clearInterval(handle);
      handle = 0;
      console.log(clearInterval(handle.id));
    }
  },
  play: function() {
    spins.init('.test', 0, 40, false);
  },
  pause: function() {
    spins.init('.test', 0, 40, true);
  }
};
```

При вызове паузы `setInterval` не останавливается

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Проблема в том что clearInterval(handle) отдает undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, рекомендую отказаться от JQ, его время уже прошло.
Во-вторых, Алексей Шиманский прав в своем ответе. По хорошему Вам нужно два метода - один старт, другой пауза. Можно, конечно, реализовать и все в одном.

**Вариант 1**

```
let spins = {
  init: function (selector, i = 0, speed, pause = false, intervalId = undefined) {
     let handle = setInterval(function () {
        i += 1;
        $(selector).css('transform', 'rotate(' + i + 'deg)');
        $(selector + ' .item-circle__image').css('transform', 'rotate(-' + i + 'deg)');
     }, speed);
     
     if(pause && intervalId){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        handle = 0;
        console.log(clearInterval(handle.id));
     }
     return handle;
  },
  play: function () {
      spins.init('.test', 0, 40, false);
  },
  pause: function () {
      spins.init('.test', 0, 40, true);
  },
};
```

Очень не правильный и код в принципе не рациональный. Но все так, как хотите Вы.
**Теперь вариант номер два:**

```
const spins = {
    timerId: undefined,
  init: (selector, speed, i = 0) => {
     return setInterval(() => {
        i += 1;
        $(selector).css('transform', 'rotate(' + i + 'deg)');
        $(selector + ' .item-circle__image').css('transform', 'rotate(-' + i + 'deg)');
     }, speed);
  },
  stopTimer: (intervalId) => {
    return clearInterval(intervalId);
  },
  play: () => {
      this.timerId = this.init('.test', 40);
  },
  pause: () => {
    this.stopTimer(this.timerId);
  },
};
```

PS: почитайте про стрелочные функции, почитайте про this, почитайте про переменные (const, let, var - чтобы никогда ее не использовать) и их область видимости, почитайте про setTimeout и почитайте про селекторы и работу с DOM в JS, чтобы выкинуть JQ из своего проекта.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что и при `play` и при `pause` ты вызываешь один и тот же метод. В итоге при `play` запускается один интервал, а при `pause` запускается другой и он же тормозится, а первый остаётся работать. Нужно запоминать идентификатор где-то вне метода. И вызывать при паузе только `clearInterval` без обращения к `init`

Comment: Не совсем пойму как это реализовать учитывая что мне нужно передавать параметры ?

Comment: а зачем их передавать? вот например для паузы так важны параметры speed и i ? не думаю. а селектор очень важен для `clearInterval`? нет. так зачем надо их передавать?